# "Silent" Apache redirect from folder to subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a blog that currently runs on a subdomain (blog.mydomain.com) but I would like to relocate it to appear to be in a folder (mydomain.com/blog).

To achieve this, I'd like all requests to `mydomain.com/blog/*` to be redirected silently to `blog.mydomain.com/*` but *without changing the URL the user sees*. I thought there might be a 30x redirect that would help me, but I can't find one, and my attempts with [P] redirects have been unsuccessful, but I'm not sure I'm even on the right track.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot redirect from different domains internally that includes sub domains using rewrite rules. You would have to use proxy or similar solutions.

Comment: @Prix No? So I guess the solution would be to relocate the blog so it actually *is* in the folder, and then "non-silently" redirect old requests to the subdomain to the correct, new folder path?

Comment: Yep, pretty much that unless you know how to setup proxy within apache which is a hassle and you would be better of doing the above mentioned change if you can as proxy will impose many other bad things